# I wrote a parser for a calendar, but can not read it

Tags: python, calendar

```
import codecs

fileIN ="calendar.ics "
fileOUT="newCalendar.ics "
fd =codecs.open(fileIN,"r ","utf −8")
line=fd.readline()
head=""

#set the headers of the file in var head
while(line != "BEGIN:VEVENT\ r \n") :
   head+=line
   line=fd.readline()

#set all the events in a list of events
while (line!="END:VCALENDAR\ r \n") :
   newEvent=line
   line=fd.readline()
   while(line != "END:VEVENT\ r \n") :
      newEvent+=line
      line=fd.readline()
   newEvent+=line
   line=fd.readline()

# last line
tail=line
fd.close()

#print calendar with only first event on newCalendarFile
file =codecs.open(fileOUT ,"w","utf −8")
file.write(head)
file.write(newEvent)
file.write( tail )
file.close()
```

I created a parser to select my programation cours and my practical course from all the groups!
But I have a problem to read the script, there is this message error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\\Desktop\projet3.py", line 5, in <module>
    fd =codecs.open(fileIN,"r ","utf −8")
  File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\codecs.py", line 895, in open
    file = builtins.open(filename, mode, buffering)
ValueError: invalid mode: 'r b'
```

Comment: That line does not exist in the code you posted.  Also you have a very unusual and somewhat unreadable coding style where you place space characters in strange places.  I think the problem you might be facing might be related to the space between the r and b.  Edit your post to include the code you are  having problems with.

Comment: please add the language tag.  Otherwise it doesn't compile on my Atari.

Comment: I changed the code, i didn't have noticed the spaces, maybe from copy paste ! and I put the all message error

Comment: Even after your edit almost all of your literal strings (apart from the `"w"`) still have one or more spaces that shouldn't be there. Most of them will cause errors or incorrect behaviour. Putting spaces at the end of file names won't cause an error, but such file names are _very_ annoying & should be avoided.

Comment: thankx so much I understood my mistake !